# Atata - How to switch to new browser window by using Atata framework?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, atata

I am new to Atata framework. When I click a link in my webpage, it opens in a new window. How to switch to the new window using Atata framework?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Go.ToNextWindow<TPageObject>()` method. For example:

```
Go.To<SomePage>().
    // Do some actions.
    ButtonThatOpensWindow.Click();

Go.ToNextWindow<SomeOtherPage>(). // Switches to newly opened window.
    // Do some actions in scope of new window.
    CloseWindow(); // Closes window and switches back to the previous window.

Go.To<SomePage>(navigate: false)...
   // Continue to work within the first window.
```

There is also `Go.ToWindow<TPageObject>(...)` method, which takes the name of the window and can be used for more specific switching between windows if you have more than 2 of them opened at the same time.